# GCC - Macro containing compilation flags

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, g++

Is there any macro in GCC that contain compilation flags used to compile the program?

I want something like this:

```
printf("Compilation flags: %s", __FLAGS__);
```

To output for example:

```
Compilation flags: -02 -g
```

Comment: it's `O2` not `02` BTW...

Comment: Well, of course. Typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: Even if there was, your code would become non-portable. Projects needing this sort of functionality let the build system do it, e.g. by having all the flags in a `CFLAGS` variable in `make` and have a rule create a `config.h` putting all these flags in a `#define` there.

Comment: That's not quite correct.A subset of the options can be found through macros: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.5/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html For example `__OPTIMIZE__
__OPTIMIZE_SIZE__
__NO_INLINE__`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know where exactly you see a "subset" here? These are just defined or undefined, they don't contain any commandline flags.

Comment: Yeah, but if you are interested in some specific options you can derive  them from here. Not sure it is what the OP is interested in though...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't buy that ;) Having just a flag telling you whether any optimization is active gives you nothing ;)

Comment: I agree with Felix. I already saw flags as `__OPTIMIZE__` but it doesn't give me any information about optimization level. I thought about Makefile but the project is managed by the IDE so it's a bit hard. I guess I will put it manually.

Comment: @zupazt3 a decent build system should have features allowing you to create a `config.h` or similar. `make` was just a (very common) example. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be of much help, but GCC has the option `-fverbose-asm` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) that will dump the command-line options used in the generated assembly as a comment.

Of course, that's only useful if you intend to read the generated assembly rather than directly assemble it